# collecting data from mysql and post email

Tags: mysql, database, forms, phpmyadmin

I will try to explain my problem. I have a form and inside of that form i have a "select a state"  option:

```
<select name="State">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Select a State</option>
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
<option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
<option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
   etc.....
</select>
```

So an example would be: customer fills out the form and selects Alabama as a state. They then submit the form and the form connects to the database where it sees the state Alabama (AL). It then collects the ip from the ip section releated to the ALbama section, and submits that to my email address along with the rest of the form information (name,email,etc...). It also needs to randomly choose an ip from Alabama because in the database i have Alabama (AL) multiple times, so it just chooses anyone of the Alabama ip's

```
+-------+---------------+
| state |      ip       |
+-------+---------------+
| AL    | 67.100.244.74 |
| AK    | 68.20.131.135 |
| AZ    | 64.134.225.33 |
+-------+---------------+
```

Thanks to some people on this forum and another one i have managed to put together some php code to show you. I have added this code to its own php file seperate from the html form

```
<?php
// visit http://php.net/pdo for more details
// start error handling

try 
{
  // connect
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=name', 'dbuser', 'pass');
  // enable error handling through exceptions
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  // create safe query
  $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT ip FROM vincer WHERE state = ? ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
  // pass data & execute query (since the data are of string type
  // and therefore can be passed in this lazy way)
  $query->execute(array($_POST['State']));
  // get value
  $ip = $query->fetchColumn();
  // print out the IP address using $ip
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
  echo "sorry, there was an error.";
  mail("email@gmail.com", "database error", $e->getMessage(), "From: email@gmail.com");
}
?>
```

next i added that php file name to the post section of the form like the code below

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="form.php">
```

OK now when i go to test it everything works and i get no errors but i do not receive the email. I have checked spam but it is not there.

So as i was not receiving the email i thought maybe i need some sort of php email form. So i added the code i already had from above to this code below

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "1stoptutorials@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "This is a test";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['State']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $state = $_POST['State']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "State: ".clean_string($state)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
if (!mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers))
{
    echo "failed to send message";
}  

?>
```

Now when i send an email i actually receive the email but the state part is not correct. This is what i receive as an email

```
First Name: afdf
Last Name: sfgsdf
Email: sd@fd.com
State: AZ
Comments: ali
```

You can see it is pulling in the two letter state, but i want it to pull in the ip number from the ip table in my database for AZ. this is what i want it too look like

```
 First Name: afdf
    Last Name: sfgsdf
    Email: sd@fd.com
    State: 64.134.225.33
    Comments: ali
```

If anyone can see what i am missing and why this is not grabbing a random ip address from the ip table it would be much appreciated

Thanks everyone

Ali

Comment: Obviously you missed fetching ip address for state.

Answer (score 0):

```
$state = $_POST['State']; // not required
```

After the above statement you're trying to

```
$email_message .= "State: ".clean_string($state)."\n";
```

This will send whatever the value of $_POST['State'] will be.
You'll have to send the ip from your form or get the ip from the above code and use

```
$email_message .= "State: ".clean_string($ip)."\n";
```

Comment: wow you are good i have been on this for weeks and i can now see the ip in the email. The only thing it is not doing is randomly picking an ip. So for example under the state alaska (AL) it is picking up the same ip every time. For each state i have about 150 different ip, i want it to randomly pick up an ip. Do you know what i am missing. Thank you so much for all your help

Comment: I am not sure, your code should give you random values. `$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT ip FROM vincer WHERE state = ? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");`